# Listen an SNMP GET request from other host

Tags: snmp

There is a way to capture an SNMP `GET` request?

I would like to execute some code when my program detects that other server has executed a `SNMP` `GET` request.

I'm using linux and https://metacpan.org/release/NetSNMP-agent

Answer (score 0):

Google for "SNMP proxy" and you will see many options.

A good `netsnmp` focused summary is at http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2012-extending-netsnmp.html ; quoting that page ...

> Net-SNMP is a suite of SNMP applications including an agent. Out of
>   the box, this agent exports a lot of information but if something is
>   missing, there are several ways to extend it. Which ones?
>
> tl;dr: in my opinion, extending Net-SNMP should be done with either of
>   those methods:
>
> ```
> using extend directive;
> using pass_persist directive;
> using AgentX protocol.
> ```